# How to prevent realm access on incorrect thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, realm

I have a model class that uses Realm to perform CRUD operations.

I am trying to perform all my operations on a serial queue.

I have declared the queue property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t realmQueue;
@property (strong,nonatomic) RLMRealm *secureRealm;
```

and I used singleton to initialize the queue:

```
+ (id)sharedInstance {
    static ActivityManager *sharedManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedManager = [[self alloc] init];

    });

    return sharedManager;
}

-(id)init{
    self.realmQueue = dispatch_queue_create("realm_activity", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    dispatch_async(self.realmQueue, ^{
    _secureRealm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
    });
    return self;
}

-(NSArray *)getDataOnSettingFilter{

    NSMutableArray *activityArr = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSString *filterSQL = //;

    RLMResults *activityResults = [[[self getActivitySource]activities] objectsWhere:filterSQL];

    dispatch_async(self.realmQueue, ^{
        [_secureRealm beginWriteTransaction];

        for (RealmActivity *activity in activityResults){

        //modify realm properties

        [_secureRealm addOrUpdateObject:activity];
        [activityArr addObject:activity];
    }
        [_secureRealm commitWriteTransaction];
    });
    return [activityArr copy];
}
```

and when I call the above method using:

```
  [[ActivityManager sharedInstance]getDataOnSettingFilter]
```

I get a crash saying realm is accessed from a incorrect thread.

What am I doing wrong here. How can I check if I am calling the realm on correct thread always ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't store a reference to a singleton `Realm` instance, since you cannot ensure that you will always  access it from the same thread. As the `Realm` documentation states,

> Instances of RLMRealm, RLMResults, or RLMArray, or managed instances
>   of RLMObject are thread-confined, meaning that they can only be used
>   on the thread on which they were created, otherwise an exception is
>   thrown

meaning that you should never try to use `RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];` to create a singleton `Realm` instance and than try to access that everywhere from your app.

You could try using `RLMThreadSafeReference` to create references to `Realm` objects that can be safely shared between threads, but as the [Passing instances across threads](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#passing-instances-across-threads) part of the documentation states, these references can only be used once, so they can't be reused as a singleton.

However, there is no need for such thing, since every time you call `RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];`, the framework automatically creates a reference to your currently used `Realm` on the thread you are on enabling you to safely interact with it as long as you don't leave that thread.

The best way to use `Realm` in a thread-safe way is to create a new reference to your `Realm` using `RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];` every time you move between threads and need to access your `Realm`. This way you can ensure that you will never get the incorrect thread exception.

Comment: thanks, I found another reason, realm object created on a realm queue is accessed on main thread in cellForRow method, that case also caused crash to me. I made sure that cell customisation that uses realm is run on realm queue!